# Installing Linux on acer travelmate 8573TG

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I tried to install linux-mint 17 this weekend. The problem is I can't start neither the live dvd nor a live usb. It always gets stuck on running `/scripts/init-bottom`

A few lines above it prints

```
failed to change mode of /etc/passwd- to 0600
```

I tried several live usb tools (unetbootin, dd, win32diskimager, ...), a few usb sticks downloaded the image again ...

Then I tried installing arch. Still not working. It stops on

```
:: runing cleanup hook[udev]
calling: control
calling: info
```

(debug flag used)

The weir part is, the boot menu looks like this

```
Arch Linux archiso x86_64 UEFI USB
UEFI Shell x86_64 v1
UEFI Shell x86_64 v2
EFI Default Loader
```

According to the [documentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57056/ubuntu-appears-in-bios-menu-uefi/63607#63607) this should happen if I've got a UEFI motherboard, which I havent.

Then I noticed I've got a `ubuntu` entry showing up in the bios boot order similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57056/ubuntu-appears-in-bios-menu-uefi/63607#63607) thread. I had ubuntu installed probably 2 years ago for a few month and windows 7 afterwards with no problems.

By the way, booting an old ubuntu live cd works.

EDIT:

Since I can boot an EFI Shell I guess it is an UEFI Bios. However the manual doesn't mention it at all, it looks like an old BIOS and it's not possible to change anything UEFI related in it.

A `ver` command in the EFI Shell reports

```
EFI Specification Revision  : 2.0
EFI Vendor                  : Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
EFI Revision                : 4660.22136
```

Comment: Is Secure Boot enabled or disabled in your BIOS?

Comment: @eyoung100 There is no option for secure boot in the BIOS, only TPM (Trusted Platform Module) and thats disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try noefi Kernel Boot Option!

Comment: Please explain how to do this and what it means. … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.